# How to determine if a PseudoClass is set in javafx

Tags: javafx, pseudo-class

I have looked around but not found anything that does what I want.  As part of a validation of user input data on a form I use a PseudoClass to change the formatting to visually highlight required fields.  I would like to do one final check on that data before writing a file and thought that the PseudoClass setting would be a good way to do it.

```
private static final PseudoClass errorClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");
segmentFile.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
```

I tried

```
segmentFile.getPseudoClassStates();
```

But that just returns either a null list or a list that contains "error".  I am hoping for a boolean return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that just returns either a null list or a list that contains "error".

This statement is wrong. [`getPseudoClassStates`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getPseudoClassStates--) returns a `ObservableSet<PseudoClass>`.

Anyways any `Collection` provides a [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method to check, if a specific element is contained in it.

In this case:

```
boolean hasError = segmentFile.getPseudoClassStates().contains(errorClass);
```

Comment: I completely missed the contains method.  By "list" that was my Python background coming out.  When I printed the getPseudoClassStates I got a [] or [error].  This gets me what I needed to finish the validation, thank you.